# how to mount docker-compose command from host into docker-container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, duplicati

I would like to run `docker-compose start` and `docker-compose stop` within a docker-container.
Equivalently one can simply try to run `docker-compose --version` successfully.

I've already managed to get `docker --version` run by simply add two lines (see below).

The container seems to use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The **docker-compose file** looks as follows:

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  duplicati-2:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/duplicati
    container_name: duplicati-2
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - CLI_ARGS= #optional
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /mnt/myBackups:/backups
      - /opt/docker:/source:ro
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------- needed to run docker -------------------------------------
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------what must stand down here to run docker-compose?---------
      - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
      - /usr/bin/python3:/usr/bin/python3
#---------------------------------------------------------------------


    ports:
      - 8300:8200
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I've already found the requirements to generally run `docker-compose --version` here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

I'm afraid of all needed dependencies and libs for python3 and so on.
I don't want to pollute my docker-container with all of those libraries from the host machine when stupidly mount the whole `/lib/*` and `/usr/bin` directories from host.

So my question is:
Which mounts do I have to add to my docker-compose file at minimal so that i can run `docker-compose` within the container?

Comment: Why do you want to just run `docker-compose --version` inside a container? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: duplicati is a backup-software. This can do really easy sequential backups to an arbitrary storage. I would like to backup my docker-folders. Therefore i have to stop those first bec. of included databases.

With `docker-compose down` and `docker-compuse up -d` afterwards this could be done really simple. `docker-compose --version` is simply for testing if docker-compose in general works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run `docker-compose` from inside your container, you need to install it in your image's Dockerfile.  There aren't really good shortcuts around this.

```sh
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      docker-compose \
      docker.io
```

In the particular case of Compose, it's a Python application with involved library dependencies, so you need the *exact* Python from the host and a hard-to-specify subset of the `/usr/lib/python3` tree.  (See for example this [list of files](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/docker-compose/filelist) from the Debian Buster `docker-compose` package.)  More generally, bind-mounting binaries from the host into a container tends to not go well since applications can have things like shared-library dependencies or content in `/usr/share` that won't appear in the container.

Also in the particular case of Compose, actually running this will be awkward, since you need to bind-mount the host directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` into the container to be able to use it.  And in general, anything that has access to the host's Docker socket can pretty trivially root the entire host.  I'd think hard as to whether there's another way to run your higher-level application that doesn't involve needing Compose inside a container.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  compose:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - .:/compose
    working_dir: /compose
    environment:
      COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: current-directory-name
    command: /bin/true
  web:
    image: busybox
    command: httpd -f -h /www
    volumes:
      - .:/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

```sh
# This will technically work
docker-compose run compose \
  docker-compose up -d web
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I realized for my purposes going without `docker-compose` would be the better solution. For only start and stop a container in duplicati it would be overkíll. Pure docker commands are then good enough.

Comment: Use a [native Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) if you can; if not, installing the Docker CLI using this same approach will be more reliable than bind-mounting the host's `docker` binary.  Be very very careful about security concerns, since a shell-injection attack calling `docker` can pretty straightforwardly root the whole host.